# How to fix the error that involve array while building a log analyzer?

Tags: java, arrays, logging

I have faced a problem when writing a code which involve in analyzing log file.
The code is as below:

```
package trial;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class LogAnalyzer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Read log file
        String logFileName = "C:\\Users\\mingc\\Downloads\\extracted_log2.txt\\";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFileName));
        String line;
        List<LogEntry> logEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        int createdCount = 0;
        int endedCount = 0;
        long totalTime = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("[2022-06-01T") && (line.contains("_slurm_rpc_submit_batch_job") || line.contains("sched: Allocate") || line.contains("_slurm_rpc_kill_job") || line.contains("_job_complete"))) {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Extract useful information from each line of the log file
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    String timestamp = parts[0];
                    String level = parts[1];
                    String message = parts[2];
                    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(timestamp.substring(1, timestamp.length() - 1));
                    if (line.contains("_slurm_rpc_submit_batch_job")) {
                        createdCount++;
                    } else if (line.contains("_job_complete")) {
                        endedCount++;
                        String jobId = parts[5].substring(7);
                        String exitStatus = parts[6].substring(13);
                        if (exitStatus.equals("0")) {
                            String startTime = parts[0];
                            String endTime = parts[0];
                            Date start = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(startTime.substring(1, startTime.length() - 1));
                            Date end = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(endTime.substring(1, endTime.length() - 1));
                            long diffInMillies = Math.abs(end.getTime() - start.getTime());
                            totalTime += diffInMillies;
                        }
                    } else if (line.contains("sched: Allocate")) {
                        String partition = parts[8].substring(9);
                        // increment a counter for the partition
                    } else if (line.contains("_slurm_rpc_kill_job")) {
                        String user = parts[8].substring(3);
                        // increment a counter for the user
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.close();
            // display the results
            System.out.println("Number of jobs created: " + createdCount);
            System.out.println("Number of jobs ended: " + endedCount);
            if (endedCount > 0)
                System.out.println("Average execution time of jobs: " + totalTime / endedCount);
            // display the number of jobs by partition
            Map<String, Integer> partitionCount = new HashMap<>();
            partitionCount.put("EPYC", 0);
            partitionCount.put("Opteron", 0);
            partitionCount.put("GPU", 0);
            for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
                partitionCount.put(entry.partition, partitionCount.get(entry.partition) + 1);
            }
            System.out.println("Number of jobs by partition:");
            System.out.println("EPYC: " + partitionCount.get("EPYC"));
            System.out.println("Opteron: " + partitionCount.get("Opteron"));
            System.out.println("GPU: " + partitionCount.get("GPU"));
            // display the number of jobs causing error and the corresponding user
            Map<String, Integer> errorCount = new HashMap<>();
            for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
                if (entry.level.equals("error")) {
                    String[] parts = entry.message.split(":");
                    String user = parts[0];
                    errorCount.put(user, errorCount.getOrDefault(user, 0) + 1);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Number of jobs causing error and the corresponding user:");
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : errorCount.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    class LogEntry {
        Date timestamp;
        String level;
        String message;
        String partition;

        public LogEntry(Date timestamp, String level, String message, String partition) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.level = level;
            this.message = message;
            this.partition = partition;
        }
    }
}
```

The error stated when I run is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 7
at trial.LogAnalyzer.main(LogAnalyzer.java:51)
```

May I know how should I fix the error? Thank you :)

Comment: Which is line 51? Also please post at least part of the log file. Bear in mind you should be using `LocalDateTime`, not `Date`

Comment: Thanks for the remind. this is my first time posting question, I apologize behalf on my mistake

Comment: [2022-06-01T01:02:35.148] _slurm_rpc_submit_batch_job: JobId=42802 InitPrio=19758 usec=589
[2022-06-01T01:02:36.012] sched: Allocate JobId=42802 NodeList=gpu05 #CPUs=32 Partition=gpu-v100s
[2022-06-01T01:02:52.084] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=42802 uid 548200045
[2022-06-01T01:17:06.607] _job_complete: JobId=42784 WEXITSTATUS 0

Comment: Don't apologise - just post the info I mentioned (in your question formatted *as code*)

Comment: this is a part of the content inside the log file ^^

Comment: *(in your question **formatted as code**)*

Comment: *} else if (line.contains("sched: Allocate")) {* The bit of the log file you posted (badly) with that substring only contains 5 parts, so trying to access part 9 (`parts[8]`) is going to fail

Answer (score 0):

Without the log is hard to say for sure, but that exception is when you try to access the place in memory from an array that is not allocated.
Meaning you have Array A = [x, y, z];

if you try to access position 2 of the array, it will return z since arrays start in position 0. But if you go to A[3] an exception will be thrown of the type ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

In your case im guessing the "parts" array has a length of 8 (max index is 7) and you are trying to access the position [8] here:
`String user = parts[8].substring(3);`

This will cause an index out of bounds, if what you want is the 8th element, the position in the array would be the 7.

If you provide the logfile, i can confirm this, if not you can debug if using an IDE or just sout the "parts" array just before that line, so as to check what's inside it and confirm theres 8 elements (last element will be on position 7, not 8)

Edit: with the log provided, in the line that matches the conditional. the array obtained would be the following:

```
[0] [2022-06-01T01:02:36.012]     
[1] sched:    
[3] Allocate    
[4] JobId=42802     
[5] NodeList=gpu05     
[6] #CPUs=32     
[7] Partition=gpu-v100s
```

If you are trying to get the last element it would be parts[7]

Comment: Thank you for helping me ^_^ I will try fixing the other errors base on your answer.

Comment: Anytime :) let me know if you managed to solve the issue presented, and if you need further help, don't hesitate in asking.